# N2 CMS, all CMS icons link to default.aspx?Page=

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, n2, n2cms

been using N2 CMS for a while now, good CMS system.

One thing thats been bugging me ever since ive used it is the icon links to each CMS Object in the N2 Admin page always link to /default.aspx?Page='SomeNumber'.

it appears that 'SomeNumber' references the URI Name entry that is has a little pad lock next to it.

my question is...

how can i change URI Name to the actual URL, so when i click a CMS icon it will bring up the page that CMS object releates to rather than a not found page.

Any help is most appricatied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the TemplateURL Attribute like so...

```
[PageDefinition(Name="GreenCars",
                Description="The Green Cars CMS Page",
                ToolTip="The tooltip",
                IconUrl = "/N2/Resources/icons/basket_error.png",
                TemplateUrl = "/GreenCars"
                )]
```